# DispatcherTimer becomes slow for every minute in updating UI

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I have implemented a DispatcherTimer with databinding which would act like a stopwatch or counting timer to display the time elapsed during an audio call. (as you can see in your mobile phones)

The following code is becoming slow for every minute by "1 second" which is not good in calculating the bill. Can you please tell me where I am wrong ?

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer; 
int seconds = 0;
public string Counter { get; set; }
public Timer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);         
    }
  private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       Counter = (seconds / 3600).ToString() + ":" + (seconds / 60).ToString("00") + ":" + (seconds % 60).ToString("00");
       NotifyPropertyChanged("Counter");
       seconds++;
    }
```

I compared this timer with other stop watches both in Internet and also in mobile, this timer is getting delayed by a second for each minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are relying on the timer, and it seems to be consistently inaccurate by the same amount.

Why don't you take a point in time and store that,

```
private DateTime startTime;

public Timer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Counter = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString();
    ...
}
```

Actually taking the code like this shows why you are having a problem. The ToString method there shows the counter more accurately including milliseconds, and it turns out the timer is not firing every 1 second, but more like every 1.01 seconds.

I am getting values like this,

```
1.008
1.02
1.031
1.03901
```

etc.

You can then replace the above with this,

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime);
        Counter = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", elapsedTime);
```

And it will be formatted like you had it before with no milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I also tested with System.Timers.Timer and its the same problem. can you recommend me anyother?

Comment: as Darren Kopp said, I think my problem is in calculation of the seconds than the timer, can you please throw some light on that?

Comment: So what do you mean it is getting delayed by a second every minute, is it counting up properly and then stuttering at 59 seconds?

Comment: It is working fine for me in a console app. I'll try it in WPF.

Comment: so if you compare this timer with any other, both will be counting the same seconds for the first minute but from the second minute, the other timer will be ahead of this by one second and from the third minute , the other time is ahead by 2 seconds and it goes...

Comment: hi peter, I tried to test with DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"); and its counting properly, hence I think there is some problem in my calculation

Comment: The timer is not accurate. I have removed my previous answer and replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't guaranteed to have the event fire at exactly 1000ms interval. You should calculate the seconds in the event rather than incrementing your own field that holds seconds

Comment: Thanks for the comment, instead of incrementing my field, can you tell me any other way to count in the event?